# How do i implement a time delay?

Tags: c#, timer, delay, wait, sleep

I'm 3 weeks into programming now so I tried to build a memory game.
Everything works fine except the delay. I've tried many different options but somehow the delay is at the end of the `Button_Click` event.

If I click the first button it changes the content but when I click the 2nd 
button no matter which `if` statement triggers, the 2nd card doesn't show. The code works fine until the end of the event THEN the delay of 3 sec happens

What I want to achieve is that you can see the 2nd card a short amount of time 
before both cards are turned back over or disappear.

P.S. - It seems to work if i add a `MessageBox` after the "delay"
but that's not the goal, so is there something like a wait for sync or something that I missed?

Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            int index = ContainderGrid.Children.IndexOf(button);

            mCounterSecondPic++;

            button.Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mImgPath[mPairs[index]]));//change content
            mPic[mCounterSecondPic-1] = mPairs[index];
            button.IsEnabled = false;

            if (mPic[0] == mPic[1] & mCounterSecondPic == 2)
            {

                mCounterSecondPic = 0;

                new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(3000); //wait for 3sec

                ContainderGrid.Children.RemoveAt(mPairs.IndexOf(mPic[0]));
                 mPairs.RemoveAt(mPairs.IndexOf(mPic[0]));
                 ContainderGrid.Children.RemoveAt(mPairs.IndexOf(mPic[0]));
                 mPairs.RemoveAt(mPairs.IndexOf(mPic[0]));

            }

            if (mCounterSecondPic == 2 & mPic[0] != mPic[1])
            {

                mCounterSecondPic = 0;

                new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(3000);//wait for3 sec

                ContainderGrid.Children.Cast<Button>().ToList().ForEach(resetbuttons =>
                {
                    resetbuttons.IsEnabled = true;
                    resetbuttons.Content = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mCardBack));

                });


            }
```

ps: it seems to work if i add a messageBox before the "delay"
but thats not the gole, so is there something like a wait for sync or something i missed?

```
                MessageBox.Show("x");
                new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(3000);
```

Comment: use a timer - start and stop it when you need to.

Comment: Look up `Task.Delay` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay

Comment: I'd like to suggest to read about game programming. The idea is to program some clock in the game that will send messages to the objects "one time interval passed". Then object can check internal state and do something if it is "time". You can check [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html) or [Reactive](http://reactivex.io/languages.html). You can use [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep) however to simple wait for N ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify the code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "START" //change content
    new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(3000); //wait for 3sec
    button.Content = "FINISH" //change content
}
```

in this way you have the following timeline:

1. you **set** the content (but do not **see/feel** it)
2. you start waiting 3 seconds
3. you end waiting 3 seconds
4. you **set** the content (but do not **see/feel** it)
5. you exit your `Button_Click` method
6. you actually **see/feel**  the content change

as you can see the content changes (at item1 and item4) have not happened immediately, but much later; this is due to fact that the UI thread was blocked inside the execution of `Button_Click` method and hence was unable to refresh the graphic.
In order to achieve what you want, you have two options:

- use `async/await`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "START" //change content
    await Task.Delay(3000); //wait for 3sec asynchronously
    button.Content = "FINISH" //change content
}
```

- use `Dispatcher`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => button.Content = "START");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => button.Content = "FINISH");
    }).Start();
}
```